# file_get_html returning empty result

Tags: php, file-get-contents, cloudflare

As specified in the title, file_get_html gives empty output. I tried the same code on localhost and it works perfectly but on server it doesn't work. I can use file_get_html for other websites but for the one I want it doesn't work.

Question update. Here is the code :

```
<?php require_once "simple_html_dom.php";

$urla="https://example.com";
 echo $urla;
$html=@file_get_html($urla);
if(!empty($html)){
echo 'Great';}
?>
```

I think my IP or something else was blacklisted. I am using couldflare. Any ideas how to solve this?

I already tried curl but it gives a captcha challenge from Cloudflare.

Thanks.

Comment: *I tried the same code on localhost and it works perfectly but on server it doesn't work* Which code did you try ?

Comment: See here quick start https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. It just tells you how to use simple html dom. I have been using it for years. It's a problem of IP or something else. Any help?

Comment: up please. Any help